# CefSharp ProgressBar for indicating download progress

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am making a web browser based on CefSharp. When I try to download a file from the web, it prompts me to save the file, and when I press Save, it downloads the file without indicating any progress percentage. I want to add a ProgressBar to show download progress. How can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/b47731de5ec09130a83c11e0d0776e9c245e95b7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `IDownloadHandler` for that.

Suppose you have a browser control named `Browser` and a `ProgressBar` named `Bar`in your XAML, you can do this in your code behind:

```
Browser.DownloadHandler = new MyDownloadHandler(Bar);
```

Here's the code for the `MyDownloadHandler`:

```
public class MyDownloadHandler : IDownloadHandler {
    private ProgressBar _bar;

    public MyDownloadHandler(ProgressBar bar) {
        _bar = bar;
    }

    public void OnBeforeDownload(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback callback) {

    }

    public void OnDownloadUpdated(IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback callback) {
        _bar.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
            Debug.Print("{0}/{1} bytes", downloadItem.ReceivedBytes, downloadItem.TotalBytes);

            _bar.Maximum = downloadItem.TotalBytes;
            _bar.Value = downloadItem.ReceivedBytes;
        }));
    }
}
```