# How to make a file download progress bar in WinForms?

Tags: winforms, download, progress-bar

I'm making a web browser with CefSharp. I just implemented downloads 2 days ago but there is no progress bar to go along with the download. How do I make the progress bar show download progress?

Comment: probably duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106707/cefsharp-progressbar-for-indicating-download-progress

Comment: i'm using a winform instead of an xaml

Comment: You can change the code similar to this  this solution. With handler and progress bar of winforms and invoke ui

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Making things clearer

Add a ProgressBar Control to your Form and **add a BackgroundWorker Component** alongside it to your form. Figure out your file size first:

```
Int64 bytes_total= Convert.ToInt64(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"])
```

This is code from Alex's amazing answer which can be found here:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;
    backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
    backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Replace this code with a way to figure out how much of the file you have already downloaded and then use backgroundworker1.ReportProgress and send the percentage completion of the file download.
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Comment: when i put that in i get errors that say "the name "Thread" does not exist in the current context" and "the name "BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged" does not exist in the current context"

Comment: also when i put Int64 bytes_total= Convert.ToInt64(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]) i get an error that says client does not exist in the current context

Comment: Edit your question and add a lot more detail, otherwise the lack of detail is ridiculous.